# FInd min Date in a date range with duplicate date

Tags: excel

Using Excel and I'd like a formula that will return the earliest date from a row that contain duplicate date.
for example:
my row has 5 different dates, 1 duplicate and one blank cell

```
    A          B           C            D            E             F
09/01/2021  08/28/2021  09/08/2021   blank cell   09/01/2021   08/15/2021
```

I am using formula `=MIN((A1:F1)`

the return should be "8/28/2021" but I'm getting "1/1/1900"
can someone please help? that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't the result be 8/15/2021? Also most likely your blank cell is not actually blank. Does your version of Excel support MINIFS?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 08/15/2021

Comment: Yes my excel support MINIFS. can you please assist. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(A1:F1*A1:F1/A1:F1,99999))
```

It will replace all the 0's with 99999 if it cannot be divided by itself (0).

(99999 is actually 10/13/2173 and was chosen at random as a date that will be later than the other dates on your list.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SMALL function:

[SMALL function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/small-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07)

[image]

My formula in column J is `=SMALL(A1:G1;1)`

Notice my date format is dd/mm/yyyy